# Unpivot in SQL - view preferred

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I need some help with unpivot data in SQL. At the moment this runs on SQL Server SSIS paket. In the future this will not be possible anymore. I hope, that you can help me.

Is it possible to create a view, that creates the result?

My starting point is:

| PK | Date | AG | ART | **MA1** | MA2 | MA3 | **BA1** | BA2 | BA3 | **BS1** | BS2 | BS3 | **BZ1** | BZ2 | BZ3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A1 | **M1** | M2 | M3 | **100** | 105 | 110 | **10** | 15 | 20 | **50** | 60 | 70 |
| 2 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A2 | **M2** | M3 |  | **100** | 113 |  | **11** | 12 | 18 | **8** | 9 |  |
| 3 | 02.01.2021 | 2 | A3 | **M3** |  |  | **100** | 2 |  | **3** |  |  | **2** |  | 6 |
| 4 | 02.01.2021 | 5 | A3 |  |  |  | **12** | 13 |  |  |  | 8 |  |  | 8 |
| 5 | 03.01.2021 | 3 | A4 | **M2** | M3 | M1 | **100** | 102 | 103 | **3** | 4 | 5 | **7** | 8 | 9 |
| 6 | 03.01.2021 | 1 | A5 | **M3** | M1 |  | **100** | 105 | 7 | **3** | 5 |  | **8** | 8 |  |

tried serveral times to make it look like this, but I failed:

My aim is:

| PK | Date | AG | ART | MA | BA | BS | BZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A1 | **M1** | **100** | **10** | **50** |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A1 | M2 | 105 | 15 | 60 |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A1 | M3 | 110 | 20 | 70 |
| 2 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A2 | **M2** | **100** | **11** | **8** |
| 2 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A2 | M3 | 113 | 12 | 9 |
| 2 | 01.01.2021 | 1 | A2 |  |  | 18 |  |
| 3 | 02.01.2021 | 2 | A3 | **M3** | **100** | **3** | **2** |
| 3 | 02.01.2021 | 2 | A3 |  | 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 02.01.2021 | 2 | A3 |  |  |  | 6 |
| 4 | 02.01.2021 | 5 | A3 |  | **12** |  |  |
| 4 | 02.01.2021 | 5 | A3 |  | 13 |  |  |
| 4 | 02.01.2021 | 5 | A3 |  |  | 8 | 8 |
| 5 | 03.01.2021 | 3 | A4 | **M2** | **100** | **3** | **7** |
| 5 | 03.01.2021 | 3 | A4 | M3 | 102 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 03.01.2021 | 3 | A4 | M1 | 103 | 5 | 9 |
| 6 | 03.01.2021 | 1 | A5 | **M3** | **100** | **3** | **8** |
| 6 | 03.01.2021 | 1 | A5 | M1 | 105 | 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 03.01.2021 | 1 | A5 |  | 7 |  |  |

MA "N",

BA "N",

BS "N"

and

BZ "N"
belong together under "N"

PK, Date, AG, Art are not touched

Each MA, BA, BS and BZ can be empty. Rows have to be shown, if MA || BA || BS || BZ are not empty. Only if all 4 are empty, the row can be removed.

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Any ideas?

Greetings
Erik

Comment: Have you had a look at the `UNPIVOT` operator? Also there are plenty of questions on [so] showing how to Unpivot; what about those questions didn't you understand? You can also use a `VALUES` table construct to unpivot, which those questions you looked at likely had examples of as well; what about that operator didn't you understand?

Comment: As an idea, I would unpivot all A/M/B columns and re-pivot (or just aggregate) them afterwards.

Comment: CROSS APPLY VALUES is the simplest and fastest way to unpivot your data, I'm pretty sure it was SQL Server 2012 that first started allowing that method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, CROSS APPLY VALUES is the easiest and best performing way to handle these types of unpivot problems.

```sql
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Test;
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE #Test
    (
        PK TINYINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
        ,[Date] DATE NOT NULL
        ,AG TINYINT NOT NULL
        ,ART VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,MA1 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,MA2 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,MA3 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BA1 VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
        ,BA2 VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
        ,BA3 VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
        ,BS1 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BS2 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BS3 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BZ1 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BZ2 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
        ,BZ3 VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    )
    ;
    GO

    INSERT INTO #Test
    (
        [Date]
        ,AG,ART
        ,MA1,MA2,MA3
        ,BA1,BA2,BA3
        ,BS1,BS2,BS3
        ,BZ1,BZ2,BZ3
    )
    VALUES
     ('01.01.2021',1,'A1',  'M1',   'M2',   'M3',   '100',  '105',  '110',  '10',   '15',   '20',   '50',   '60',   '70')
    ,('01.01.2021',1,'A2',  'M2',   'M3',   '  ',   '100',  '113',  '   ',  '11',   '12',   '18',   '8 ',   '9 ',   '  ') 
    ,('02.01.2021',2,'A3',  'M3',   '  ',   '  ',   '100',  '2  ',  '   ',  '3 ',   '  ',   '  ',   '2 ',   '  ',   '6 ')
    ,('02.01.2021',5,'A3',  '  ',   '  ',   '  ',   '12 ',  '13 ',  '   ',  '  ',   '  ',   '8 ',   '  ',   '  ',   '8 ')
    ,('03.01.2021',3,'A4',  'M2',   'M3',   'M1',   '100',  '102',  '103',  '3 ',   '4 ',   '5 ',   '7 ',   '8 ',   '9 ')
    ,('03.01.2021',1,'A5',  'M3',   'M1',   '  ',   '100',  '105',  '7  ',  '3 ',   '5 ',   '  ',   '8 ',   '8 ',   '  ')
    ;
```

```sql
    SELECT
        TST.PK
        ,TST.[Date]
        ,TST.AG
        ,TST.ART
        ,UNP.MA
        ,UNP.BA
        ,UNP.BS
        ,UNP.BZ
    FROM #Test AS TST
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
        (MA1,BA1,BS1,BZ1,1)
        ,(MA2,BA2,BS2,BZ2,2)
        ,(MA3,BA3,BS3,BZ3,3)
    ) AS UNP (MA,BA,BS,BZ,ORD)
    ORDER BY
        TST.PK
        ,TST.[Date]
        ,TST.AG
        ,TST.ART
        ,UNP.ORD
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony Hancock,
your solution works fast and is easy to implement.